# Realizar insert con variables

Tags: sql, insert, transact-sql

estoy intentando realizar varios INSERT en una tabla usando variables.
Lo hago de esta forma, junto más valores, pero para sintetizar pongo solo este:

```
declare @contador int
set @contador = 1
while @contador <= 11
BEGIN
set @query = 'insert into OFERTAS (linea)values('+@contador+')'
EXEC (@query)
print @query
set @contador = @contador + 1
END
```

Pero me retorna este error :

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 46 Error de conversión al convertir
>   el valor varchar 'insert into OFERTAS (linea)values(' al tipo de datos
>   int.
>   ¿ Alguien me puede ayudar por favor ?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: La forma en que estás usando SQL dinámico te deja abierto a ataques de SQL injection, te recomiendo usar `sp_executesql` en vez de esta forma. Por otro lado, algo como insertar valores de esta forma, no es necesario usar SQL dinámico ni un loop

Comment: y a todo esto, el error que estás recibiendo es relativamente simple. `@contador` es un `int`, por eso no lo puedes concatenar directamente con un string (sin antes convertirlo a un string también)

Comment: Esta Base de datos es de pruebas y no está expuesta a Internet, aún y así te agradezco el consejo, soy muy novato y cualquier ayuda se agradece. No había caído en convertir el `int` en `string`, ya que la tabla espera un entero.

Comment: En ese caso, te recomiendo que cuando trabajes con una base de datos trates de dejar de lado las soluciones que son de 1 registro a uno, ya que son poco eficientes.

Comment: Y en tu caso. ni siquiera necesitas SQL dinámico, si tu mismo código lo usaras directo funcionaría para lo que quieres

Comment: ¿Y como lo haría para insertar muchos registros en una misma tabla sin usar SQL dinámico? En el ejemplo hay 11 iteraciones, pero en realidad serán muchas más.

Comment: @Miguel. Eso ya es otra pregunta. Recomiendo busques primero en el sitio para confirmar que no exista una similar cuya respuesta puedas utilizar. De lo contrario, puedes crear una nueva.

Comment: Amigo, como ya te han comentado por aquí, la técnica que estás usando se denomina "sql dinámico", y es nada recomendable por muchas razones. Si nos planteas el caso completo seguro te podemos proponer alternativas mejores. Siempre, o casi siempre hay alternativas al sql dinámico. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Enigma, finalmente lo realicé de forma similar pero sin SQL dinámico, ya que como bien me indicó @Lamak, no era necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta con la funcion CAST()

```
declare @contador int
set @contador = 1
while @contador <= 11
BEGIN
set @query = 'insert into OFERTAS (linea)values('+CAST(@contador AS VARCHAR(100))+')'
EXEC (@query)
print @query
set @contador = @contador + 1
END
```

Puse como ejemplo varchar en tu caso es con el tipo de dato @query